# Как получить / обработать двойной клик по кнопке?

Tags: delphi-7, button, click

У меня есть форма и на ней `GroupBox`. У `GroupBox` `Width = 0`, при нажатии на button размер GroupBox меняется. Как сделать при двойном нажатии на `button Width GroupBox = 0`. Посмотрел на `Events` button там нету `OnDblClick`.

Comment: почему именно двойное нажатие нужно? можно просто при первом нажатии увеличивать ширину, при повторном уменьшать. Есть вроде свойство `Tag`, можно как флаг использовать.

Comment: Почему вы убрали метку VCL - вопрос про FMX ?

Comment: нет я ошибся написав VCL и удалил.

Comment: А если не VCL, то какой визуальный фреймворк еще может быть в Delphi 7 ? Укажите в вопросе плиз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделал как slippyk написал тоже все норм всем спасибо за помощь

```
 begin
          if lbl16.Tag = 0 then
            begin
              grp1.Height:=200;
              grp1.Width:=195;
              lbl16.Caption:='Скрыть';
              lbl16.Tag:= 1;
            end
            else
            begin
              grp1.Height:=200;
              grp1.Width:=0;
              lbl16.Caption:='Показать';
              lbl16.Tag:= 0;
          end;
        end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Вместо Button используйте SpeedButton. Плюс другие варианты вместо кнопки: Panel, Label и т.п.

Comment: ради примера создал  SpeedButton но при написании в DblClick   (grp1.Height:=0;
grp1.Width:=0;) не чего не происходить

Comment: @delphi если ничего не происходит - у вас где-то косяк.

Answer (score 1):

вместо button использовать Label все заработало

> "показать"
>
> ```
> grp1.Height:=200;   
> grp1.Width:=200;
> lbl1.Caption:='Скрыть';
> ```
>
> "скрыть"
>
> ```
> grp1.Height:=0;
> grp1.Width:=0;
> lbl1.Caption:='Показать';
> ```